# How to call a MVC controller and action method from HTML link text

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to MVC.
This is what i have already tried but its not going to new URL on click instead i have to right cick and select Open,then its opening and fetching correctly.

I need that it should be go on particular URL by clicking on it.

```
@Html.ActionLink("ServersStopped" + "(" + @Model.ServersStopped + ")", "FetchAllServersDown", "Home")
```

The actual html generated is

```
<a href="/Home/FetchAllServersDown">ServersStopped(1)</a>
```

Comment: Show the actual html that your generating

Comment: this is what i m getting on page,"ServersStopped(1)"

Comment: No I mean the actual html that the `Html.ActionLink()` method is generating (view the page source and copy it to the question)

Comment: <a href="/Home/FetchAllServersDown">ServersStopped(1)</a>.....Hope this you are asking

Comment: Can you show us what that action looks like in the controller?

Comment: What does the html you are trying to produce look like?

Comment: <a href="/Home/FetchAllServersDown">ServersStopped(1)</a>

Comment: Sorry, may have misunderstood - is that what you are trying to produce? Because that is what yours already produces

Comment: its showing this in  page source but it is hitting the action directly, i have to right click and select open

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `LinkExtensions.ActionLink` correctly,

To get the correct URL you are wanting to get, you pass the parameter in the routeValues argument [check here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object%29))

So, in your case, perhaps something like this

`@Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "FetchAllServersDown", new { controllerName = "Home", serversStopped = Model.ServersStopped })`

Comment: where to write controller-Home.

Comment: In Home controller this is the action   ------------------------------------  public ActionResult FetchAllServersDown()
        {
            CommonMapper commonMapper = new CommonMapper();
            List<GetAllServersDown> serversDown = commonMapper.FetchAllServersDown();
            
            return View(serversDown);

        }

Comment: Above method will return just the number of servers down in  a list

Comment: Working but not going just by clicking on that link,have to open by right click

Comment: I don't think that's ASP.NET or markup issue if the element is not clickable - perhaps a JavaScript issue?

Comment: Yes,some issue is there,because when i try to implement it in stand alone application....woo...hoo ,it works but not working in this appplication ,i have to check issue one by one...anyways thanks @andyw